# Usage of memset() in c

Tags: c, memset

I have written a small program to get used to `memset()` operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10], i;
    int t = INT_MAX;
    memset(arr, t, sizeof(arr));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);

    printf("%d",t);
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the above program is:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

2147483647
```

What is the behaviour of the `memset()` in the above program? Why is it setting the array elements to `-1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) only takes the lower eight bits of the value and fills the whole buffer with these bits. The lower eight bits of MAX_INT are all ones (`0xFF`), and thus the array is afterwards filled with all ones. For signed integers, this is -1.

Comment: Assuming int is 32 bits, a 4 byte, you mean, memset only uses bits 0 to 7 to determine the value, which they represent and put this value into target memory location?  If yes, this means also, as unsigned char  could only handle old fashioned ascii?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. bits 0 to 7 are eight bits, which is one bit more than ascii (if you don't take parity into account). But yes, if you want a pattern larger than 8 bits, you need to use a different function (wmemset comes to mind) or a for loop.

Comment: All right. You understood well and answered my question. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Memset sets the first sizeof(arr) bytes of the block of memory pointed by arr to t  interpreted as an unsigned char. So what u get when you read out ints from arr depends in the interpretation of those bytes on your platform.